# How to migrate crop coding from code behind to view model wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Being new to WPF and MVVM I searched everywhere to find a good answer to my problem. I'm creating a cropping application but I'm trying to migrate the code behind codes to a view model. I was able to bind my mouse button event by using blends interactivity triggers code is below:

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridLoadedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonUpCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <Image x:Name="LoadedImage" Margin="10" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                <Canvas  x:Name="BackPanel" Margin="10">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="selectionRectangle" Stroke="LightBlue" Fill="#220000FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
```

Now my dilema is how to migrate the actual code i used from my code behind which is shown below:

```
     private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging == false)
        {
            anchorPoint.X = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            anchorPoint.Y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(selectionRectangle, BackPanel.Children.Count);
            isDragging = true;
            BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }

    }
    private void LoadedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            double x = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            double y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
            selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
            selectionRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(x - anchorPoint.X);
            selectionRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(y - anchorPoint.Y);

            if (selectionRectangle.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                selectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            if (selectionRectangle.Width > 0)
            {
                Crop.IsEnabled = true;
                Cut.IsEnabled = true;
                BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I would need to be able to access the x and y coordinates as well as the width and height of the rectangle (which is named selection rectangle). I was thinking of creating the canvas and rectangle inside my viewmodel but that would be against the mvvm structure. I read that I could use attached properties but not familiar with it. What is the best possible way of handling this with respect to MVVM pattern. Currently I'm reading a book by Adan Nathan WPF unleashed 4 which is a great book for beginners like me but i cant seem to find anything that relates to my problem. Thanks for any help

I do have a view model code for my mouse event:

```
        #region MouseLeftButtonDown
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Point anchorPoint = new Point();
    private ICommand _mouseLeftButtonDownCommand;
    public ICommand MouseLeftButtonDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mouseLeftButtonDownCommand == null)
            {
                _mouseLeftButtonDownCommand = new RelayCommand(param => MouseLeftButtonDown());
            }
            return _mouseLeftButtonDownCommand;
        }

    }
    public void MouseLeftButtonDown()
    {
        if (isDragging == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("THis is Mouse Down");
            //anchorPoint.X = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            //anchorPoint.Y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            isDragging = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region MouseLeftButtonUp
    private ICommand _mouseLeftButtonUpCommand;
    public ICommand MouseLeftButtonUpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mouseLeftButtonUpCommand == null)
            {
                _mouseLeftButtonUpCommand = new RelayCommand(param => MouseLeftButtonUp((MouseButtonEventArgs)param));
            }
            return _mouseLeftButtonUpCommand;
        }

    }

    public void MouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isDragging)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Source.ToString());
            isDragging = false;
            //if (selectionRectangle.Width > 0)
            //{
            //    Crop.IsEnabled = true;
            //    Cut.IsEnabled = true;
            //    BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            //}
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region MouseMove
    private ICommand _mouseMoveCommand;
    public ICommand MouseMoveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mouseMoveCommand == null)
            {
                _mouseMoveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => MouseMove());
            }
            return _mouseMoveCommand;
        }

    }
    public void MouseMove()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("THis is Mouse Move");
            //double x = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            //double y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            //selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
            //selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
            //selectionRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(x - anchorPoint.X);
            //selectionRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(y - anchorPoint.Y);

            //if (selectionRectangle.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
            //    selectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

I just commented the actual code and replace it with message boxes just to test if my trigger work which it does. This 3 functions once I figure out how to make it work would draw the cropping rectangle on top of the imaged being cropped. I do have a crop button the will be enabled once the rectangle is completed and this button will be bound to another function that would be the actual cropping function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more simple than you may have thought.

What you are doing is an UserControl which userdefined behaviour. So rather than putting that XAML into your Page/View, you implement your own Control which derives from `UserControl` and implement your code as you have in your code-behind.

Since you are making a custom control, you don't have to follow MVVM for it. In fact, MVVM patter for user controls is discouraged. In your custom control you define may define a Dependency Property which holds an Object of type "SelectionRect" (you shouldn't be using Rect as it's a struct and it doesn't work well with databinding, as it creates a new copy of it each time it changes).

```
public class CropControl : UserControl 
{
    public Rect Selection
    {
        get { return (Rect)GetValue(SelectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Selection", typeof(Rect), typeof(CropControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Rect)));

    // this is used, to react on changes from ViewModel. If you assign a  
    // new Rect in your ViewModel you will have to redraw your Rect here
    private static void OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect newRect = (Rect)e.NewValue;
        Rectangle selectionRectangle = d as Rectangle;

        if(selectionRectangle!=null)
            return;

        selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newRect.X);
        selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newRect.Y);
        selectionRectangle.Width = newRect.Width;
        selectionRectangle.Height = newRect.Height;
    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging == false)
        {
            anchorPoint.X = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            anchorPoint.Y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(selectionRectangle, BackPanel.Children.Count);
            isDragging = true;
            BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }

    }
    private void LoadedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            double x = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).X;
            double y = e.GetPosition(BackPanel).Y;
            selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Math.Min(x, anchorPoint.X));
            selectionRectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Math.Min(y, anchorPoint.Y));
            selectionRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(x - anchorPoint.X);
            selectionRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(y - anchorPoint.Y);

            if (selectionRectangle.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
                selectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }

    private void LoadedImage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            if (selectionRectangle.Width > 0)
            {
                Crop.IsEnabled = true;
                Cut.IsEnabled = true;
                BackPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }

            // Set the Selection to the new rect, when the mouse button has been released
            Selection = new Rect(
                selectionRectangle.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), 
                selectionRectangle.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), 
                selectionRectangle.Width,
                selectionRectangle.Height);

        }
    }
}
```

Notice the only changes were to add `Selection = new Rect(...)` and the Dependency Property.

Then you can bind it in XAML.

```
<my:CropControl Selection="{Binding Selection,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Update:**
Your ViewModel would look something like

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel 
{
    private Rect selection;
    public Rect Selection 
    {
        get 
        {
            return selection;
        }
        set 
        {
            selection = value;

            // Or whatever the name of your framework/implementation the method is called
            OnPropertyChanged("Selection");

            // Cause ICommands to reevaluate their CanExecute methods
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); 
        }
    }

    private ICommand cropCommand;
    public ICommand CropCommand {
        get 
        {
            if(cropCommand==null)
                cropCommand = new RelayCommand(Crop, () => Selection.Width > 0); // only allow execution when Selection width > 0

            return cropCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Crop() 
    {
        // Get a copy of the selection in case it changes during execution
        Rect cropSelection = Selection; 

        // use it to crop your image
        ... 
    }
}
```

Drawing Selection = View Logic (So View)
Cropping with a Rect given by `CropControl` => Presentation/Business Logic (so ViewModel)

Doing so, allows you to reuse your `CropControl` in other applications. If you put your "selectionRect" drawing code into your ViewModel (which may be possible, but causes hard to read and maintain code), then you can't reuse it in other application, since your ViewModels are specific to your application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: First, the `Rect` struct already contains the needed properties. And second, MVVM pattern is a Presentation Model pattern, so saying "you don't have to follow MVVM for application controls" is a big mistake : UI Controls are in the View side of the MVVM pattern, and they are part of it.

Comment: When you are creating user controls one shouldn't apply MVVM **to the UserControl**. The control itself can be part of MVVM. But you don't apply MVVM to the UserControl itself

Comment: When you create a UserControl you don't split it's logic into a ViewModel like you do it when you develop an App. And what the @mcvanta attempted to do in his step is exactly that: He tried to apply MVVM to the "CropControl", which doesn't work with controls. That's why he wanted to move his code-behind code into a ViewModel and this is where he got stuck

Comment: The same problem happens, when people try to use Dependency Injection on UserControls and then "inject" their ViewModel with the logic for that UserControl. Not going to work

Comment: Whoever has downvoted your answer clearly doesn't know about UserControls in WPF. I agree with you completely, therefore +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I'm trying to analyze your suggested solution. So I should implement a custom control which is derived from user control. In the custom control class I would then create the setter and getter for the rectangle coordinates. But where do i implement the code for my mouse button events? Again the purpose of those mouse button events is to draw the rectangle on top of the image to be cropped.

Comment: Yea, but you don't implement simple Getter and Setter, it has to be Dependency Properties. Dependency Properties (see code example) in so far special, that they allow TwoWay DataBinding. If you'd call `SelectionRect = new SelectionRect(x, y, width, height)` (or just use `Rect`) from the code above, it would cause the Control to also update `Selection` in your `ViewModel`. Mouse events you register the event handler in your UserControls code-behind, which you already did in the example above

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to understand the flow of the code you have given but I cant seem to make sense of it. Using the code behind each mouse button event would access their matching function which would then form the actual triangle  displayed on top of the imaged to be cropped. So if I use your example how will this accomplish the same task? Do i bind "Selection" with each mouse button events in my Event Trigger? So does your code need me to implement the code for each mouse button events in my code behind? Would it be possible to implement my code in my viewmodel instead?

Comment: You just need to move all this code into an custom UserControl and add a Dependency Property of type Rect or SelectionRect. Each time your Selection changes, you need to update this Property (by simply assigning it). And no, you don't have to do this code in the ViewModel. This code belongs to the UserControl as it's View-specific code (drawing the rectangle). What happens with it, is part of ViewModel (the actual cropping, but not the drawing of the rectangle)

Comment: Yes you could do that, though then it wouldn't be customizable anymore. Though you could add another Dependency Property of type Rectangle and assign it a default Template for the selection object. In your Page you can override this DP with your own template allowing it to customize it (in similar fashion you override a ListView's ItemTemplate). But can't post exact code, haven't done it yet and I'm at work. For UserControls you can use the events. If you have further question, please create a new question for it :)

Comment: @Tseng This makes more sense now and appreciate you taking the time explaining. I do have a few more question if you don't mind me asking. I read about user control and they are tied with a user control xaml so I'm assuming I would need to implement one for the crop control calls, is this correct? The XAML coding i posted was just a snippet of code that is part of my main window XAML and wasn't intentionally meant to show my user control xaml (but I could implement it into one). Also, where do i place the binding in my main window xaml?

Comment: @Tseng I got this to work but I'm trying to change the size of Selection in ViewModel but nothing happens. I have OnPropertychanged in my UserControl and SetPropertyChanged on my ViewModel. I know this might be a little late to ask but can you clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM means separating View from ViewModel. The example you give is typically a View only code.

Your example seems to be a kind of selection tool, I deduce you want to get the selected content back, or at least the cropping coordinates. So the best is to transform your code in a custom control exposing a [`Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) DependencyProperty for the crop coordinates, and in your view model, you should expose a [`Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property holding the cropping rectangle coordinates, and then Bind it to your cropping control DepencyProperty.

The view is about interacting with visual aspects. The ViewModel is about holding and working with the data used by the view.

Comment: The example i have shown was just part of program which has several different function from cropping, saving, exporting and importing images. Currently I have a relay command with two delegates (execute and can execute) and viewmodel class in my view model folder. The only thing working in my view model is the import image function. I'm trying to migrate or work with one function at a time since I'm fairly new to wpf and mvvm and I'm sure I could easily get lost in the process. What I'm trying to retrieve are the mouse coordinates to draw rectangle on top of the image being cropped.